# GRAILS: createCriteria NAND

Tags: grails, createcriteria

I have a bunch of rows from my query in createCriteria, but some changes have to be made, I need to hide the rows with a 0 in a column and a letter A in other column, but i won't hide them if they have 0 and another letter , how can I make this in createCriteria? my only solution is using a NAND, but it doesn't exist I think...

```
             createCriteria.list{
                     nand{
                          eq('value',0)
                          eq('letter','A')  
                     }
             }


             TABLE
             VALUE          LETTER
             0              A                HIDE
             0              B                NOT HIDE
             1              A                NOT HIDE
```

any suggestion?

Comment: What are the condition in SQL format? SELECT * From MyEntity Where value==0 and letter<>'A' ?

Comment: but it can be done the other way too

Answer (score 2):

You can use `and` and `ne` for:

```
createCriteria.list {
    and {
        ne 'value', 0
        ne 'letter', 'A'
    }
}
```

Comment: this one doesn't work, because it will not show those with A or 0 , I need both to exists in the same row to hide

Comment: This one has to work for you. You are doing something wrong if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

try "ne", not - equal

```
createCriteria.list{
   and{
      eq('value',0)
      ne('letter','A')  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using HQL you can do:

```
def result = Object.executeQuery(
   "from Object o where o not in " +
       "(from Object o2 where o2.value = '0' and o2.letter = 'A')",
  )
```